# In SQL Server, how do I move data from multiple rows into one row, and keep the data in the correct columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table where the row of information is split into 3 or 4 rows like below.  I created a [SEQ_NO] column to keep the data in the correct order before I tried moving anything.

| SEQ_NO | EMP_ID | FNAME | LNAME | ADDRESS | CITY | STATE | ZIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A12345 | FRED | BUBLEBEAN | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | A12345 | NULL | NULL | 101 MAIN ST. | FLINT | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | A12345 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | MI | 98765 |
| 4 | L354 | ALMA | TREE | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | L354 | NULL | NULL | 345 MAIN ST. | FLINT | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | L354 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | MI | 98765 |

Now, I would like move the data to be in one row to look like the like below but I do not know where to start.

| SEQ_NO | EMP_ID | FNAME | LNAME | ADDRESS | CITY | STATE | ZIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A12345 | FRED | BUBLEBEAN | 101 MAIN ST. | FLINT | MI | 98765 |
| 2 | L354 | ALMA | TREE | 345 MAIN ST. | FLINT | MI | 98765 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select EMP_ID, MAX(FNAME), MAX(LNAME), MAX(ADDRESS),
       MAX(CITY), MAX(STATE), MAX(ZIP)
from t
group by EMP_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: @Dexter . . . I removed `SEQ_NO`.  That doesn't seem like something you need in the final result.